# Multiple Resource Configuration in Android

Tags: android, version, locale, android-resources

I need some version specific dimen.xml file for certain locales such as if the locale is France I want to show dialog text sizes in 14dp when the API version is 21 or 22. 
However, if the locale is US or France but the API version is not 21 and 22 dialog text sizes should be 18dp.

The problem is in API versions 21 and 22. System dialog button texts are truncated in these versions if they are too long.

```
values-fr/values-v22.
```

Is it possible in Android?
or should I do

```
values-v22/values-fr
```

In both options that I have written above are not working. Is there anyway that I can do configuration on xml in compile time but not in run time. Doing this programmatically will decrease the performance and also overkill.

Answer (score 0):

This documentation could help you http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Android supports layouts by locale /res/layout-de/mylayout.xml
They do warn that doing so can make your application harder to maintain
and that you should try to make a single layout work.

More here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need this solely for French AND platform version 22 or higher you can do values-fr-v22. You may combine any set of qualifiers in the order listed here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Perhaps you should consider if it's a good idea to stay consistent across platforms and use 14dp all the time though? Just a thought.